Data splitting for OLS regression
This is what I have done ::
divided my dataset into training and testing sets--> got significant features via. feature selection using sequential feature selector ( MLxtend) on the training set--> used significant features to fit a linear predictive model--> test the model on the testing set.
However, the error for both my test and training set is not small. Should I reconsider the decision to split my dataset?  Any help is much appreciated!!
(Not a data science person)

It is not clear the ratio that you have used to do the train-test split. If the dataset is small, you can try with cross-validation and check the metrics. Also, can try with various rations 80-20, 30-70 and compare the metrics.
Post this, you may also check using different techniques for feature selection - Lasso, tree-based etc.
